# Company name in welcome message

Tags: customer, magento2.2

Is it possible to put in the welcome message the company name instead of customer name?

Answer (score 0):

On the Admin sidebar, go `Content > Design > Configuration > Select your current theme`.

Choose the store view you want to change the welcome message.

Under **Action** column, open the **Edit** mode.

Scroll down and expand the Header section. Then, enter the Welcome Text that you want to appear.

[image]

**EDIT:**

So for getting dynamic customer company name. You have to override file.

> vendor\magento\module-theme\Block\Html\Header.php

```
public function getWelcome()
{
    if (empty($this->_data['welcome'])) {
        $this->_data['welcome'] = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            'design/header/welcome',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
    }
    return __($this->_data['welcome']);
}
```

Comment: Yes I know this. What I want to know is how to put dinamically the name of the company associated to the customer instead of his name and surname